# VB6 - Reading a single bit over an RS232 line/ COM port

Tags: vb6, serial-port

I am currently working on writing a little script on VB6 to replace a script running on a UNIX machine. What that script does is wait for the UPS system to close a switch which is then received by a COM port and a driver shuts down the UNIX machine. I want to do that for a Windows PC but it is giving me some trouble.

I built a connector, according to the schematics I have, bridging pins 7 and 8 and connecting a switch between pins 2 and 3 (RXD and TXD). Flipping the switch on is exactly the same as the UPS system doing it.

```
Private Sub shutdownPC()

Dim inStr As Variant

myCom.CommPort = 1
myCom.Settings = "9600,e,7,1"
myCom.RThreshold = 1
myCom.InputLen = 0
myCom.InputMode = comInputModeBinary
myCom.InBufferCount() = 0
myCom.PortOpen = True

'Shell ("shutdown.exe -s -t01")

If myCom.CommEvent = comEvReceive Then
    inStr = myCom.Input
End If

End Sub
```

This is my code so far. I have included the MSComm library and added an MSComm object to my form. When I use comInputModeBinary and comInputModeText, I get "No variables" and "" on myCom.Input respectively. Using Powershell I can see that the COM1 port is working.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure how just shorting RD & TD results in a valid character, or any at all.  It would seem to make more sense to have the switch toggle one of the RS-323 control lines.  Usually at least some form of RS-232 signal buffer is used, not simply shorting wires to make contact.

Comment: I would try writing to the port, with a short timeout. I would then monitor for the data received eventhandler to be triggered which would signify that the switch was closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> connecting a switch between pins 2 and 3 (RXD and TXD)

That would create a **loopback.**
That is only useful if your program is sending out test messages.
If nothing is received, then the switch is still open.  When the switch closes, then the program will begin receiving the messages it sent.

> Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Your program cannot wait passively.
It has to poll the UPS by sending bytes out and then check if any of the data is received back.

Answer (score 0):

You either have to loop or put in an event handler as your code will execute before anything in the external world happens. Looping wastes battery life and slows computers down. The helpfile is at C:\Windows\HELP\COMM98.CHM.

OnComm Event

The OnComm event is generated whenever the value of the CommEvent property changes, indicating that either a communication event or an error occurred.

Syntax

```
Private Sub object_OnComm ()
```

The OnComm event syntax has these parts:

Part Description 
object Anobject expression that evaluates to an object in the Applies To list.

Remarks

The CommEvent property contains the numeric code of the actual error or event that generated the OnComm event. Note that setting the RThreshold or SThreshold properties to 0 disables trapping for the comEvReceive and comEvSend events, respectively.